# Nodejs socket.io server active handles keep increasing

Tags: node.js, socket.io

nodejs socket.io server's active handles are not reducing. Active handles' count reached 4080 in 6 hours and the server can not accept any new connections. What are the reasons an active handle might not close ?

Comment: i. Is it increasing per  connection as well on every recurring connect? ii. You have added timeout etc. properly every connection?

Comment: its increasing with every new connection. does a timeout run from socket event keep the socket alive after disconnect even if the timeout does not hold socket refererence ???

Comment: Basically they are not getting cleared, you can find multiple references on that. Recurring connections on very reconnect socket.io

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691887/what-are-active-handles-in-node-js